# Refresh table after an insert/update in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, resources

My webapp is a CRUD in which there is a list of users and operations associated with them (insert, delete, ecc).
To add a user must fill in the fields of a modal ( bootstrap - ui ). 
The problem is that the list is not updated automatically after insertion.

This is my code:
HTML:

```
 ...
ng-repeat="p in list"
 ...
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource' ]);

app.controller("FirstController", [
        '$scope',
        'ElementFactory',
        'ElementsFactory',
        '$uibModal',
        function($scope, ElementFactory, ElementsFactory, $uibModal) {

            $scope.list = ElementsFactory.query();  

            $scope.add = function() {

                var modalAddInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation : true,
                    templateUrl : 'addModal.html',
                    controller : 'addModalController',
                    resolve : {
                        element : function() {
                            return $scope.element;
                        } 
                    }
                });
            };

        } ]);

app.controller("addModalController", function($scope, $uibModalInstance,
        ElementsFactory, element) {

    $scope.element = element;



    $scope.addCancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.addElement = function() {
        ElementsFactory.create($scope.element, function(){
            //REFRESH TABLE HERE ********************** 
            $uibModalInstance.close();
        });



    };

});

app.factory('ElementsFactory', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('rest/all', {}, {
        query : {
            method : 'GET',
            isArray : true
        },
        create : {
            method : 'POST'
        }
    });
} ]);
```

Once add the new item , this is only visible after page refresh and not automatically . What is the code to be inserted where I indicated to you that the table will automatically update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add new item to $scope.list in FirstController. You are nowhere updating $scope.list once the new item is added.

```
    app.controller("addModalController", function($rootScope,$scope, $uibModalInstance,
            ElementsFactory, element) {

        $scope.element = element;



        $scope.addCancel = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        $scope.addElement = function() {
            ElementsFactory.create($scope.element, function(){
                //REFRESH TABLE HERE ********************** 
                $rootScope.$broadcast("Element Added");
                $uibModalInstance.close();
            });



        };

    });

app.controller("FirstController", [
        '$scope',
        'ElementFactory',
        'ElementsFactory',
        '$uibModal',
        function($scope, ElementFactory, ElementsFactory, $uibModal) {

            $scope.list = ElementsFactory.query();  

            $scope.add = function() {

                var modalAddInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation : true,
                    templateUrl : 'addModal.html',
                    controller : 'addModalController',
                    resolve : {
                        element : function() {
                            return $scope.element;
                        } 
                    }
                });
            };

            $scope.$on("Element Added",function(pevent,padata){
             $scope.list = ElementsFactory.query(); 
           })
        } ]);
```

Comment: I thought of writing : $scope.list = ElementsFactory.query();  after insert, but it does not work because it does not take the scope.

Comment: You can add $rootScope.$broadcast from modalcontroller once inserted, and have maincontroller listen to this broadcast. On hearing it main controller wound run query call from element factory(put the brodacast right at  //REFRESH TABLE HERE **********************  place)